# quill add tooltip on custom blot

Tags: quill

I can't figure out how to add a tooltip on a created custom blot. Something like what is natively happening on links

[image]

My custom blot is displayed in the text editor with cusom tag

```
   class CustomBlot extends BlockEmbed {
          static create(value) {

            let node = super.create();
            node.setAttribute('object', "instrument");
            node.setAttribute('id', value.id);
            node.innerHTML = `
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">${value.name}</button>
            </div>
            `;
            return node;
          }

          static formats(node) {
            return node.getAttribute('id');
          }
        }
        CustomBlot.blotName = 'custom';
        CustomBlot.tagName = 'my-custom-tag';
        Quill.register(CustomBlot);
```

So the inserted code in my editor is between these tags

```
<my-custom-tag>some html</my-custom-tag>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while, but for anyone interested in the subject, please, see the following link:

https://github.com/loagit/Quill-Examples-and-FAQ